# How to send data from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python

How can i send this list to list in Python script? This is so big for sending as arguments. Thank you.

```
 List<String> cefList= new List<String>();
               for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
                cefList.Add("CEF:0|ArcSight|ArcSight|6.0.3.6664.0|agent:030|Agent [test] type [testalertng] started|Low| 
    eventId=1 mrt=1396328238973 categorySignificance=/Normal categoryBehavior=/Execute/Start 
    categoryDeviceGroup=/Application catdt=Security Mangement categoryOutcome=/Success 
    categoryObject=/Host/Application/Service art=1396328241038 cat=/Agent/Started 
    deviceSeverity=Warning rt=1396328238937 fileType=Agent 
    cs2=<Resource ID\="3DxKlG0UBABCAA0cXXAZIwA\=\="/> c6a4=fe80:0:0:0:495d:cc3c:db1a:de71 
    cs2Label=Configuration Resource c6a4Label=Agent 
    IPv6 Address ahost=SKEELES10 agt=888.99.100.1 agentZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight 
    System/Private Address Space 
    Zones/RFC1918: 888.99.0.0-888.200.255.255 av=6.0.3.6664.0 atz=Australia/Sydney 
    aid=3DxKlG0UBABCAA0cXXAZIwA\=\= at=testalertng dvchost=SKEELES10 dvc=888.99.100.1 
    deviceZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Private Address Space Zones/RFC1918: 
    888.99.0.0-888.200.255.255 dtz=Australia/Sydney _cefVer=0.1");
                }
```

Comment: Use sockets to pass data between them

Comment: The simplest way is to print it to stdout in C# and use an anonymous pipe to read the data in python.  But it does depend on the relationship between the two processes.  Does the C# run the python, does python run the C#, or are they unrelated?

Comment: C# run the Python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your C# program runs the python script, I guess the easiest solution would be to redirect the standard input of the python process:

```
     Process pyProc = Process.Start(
        new ProcessStartInfo("python.exe", @"/path/to/the/script.py")
        {
           RedirectStandardInput = true,
           UseShellExecute = false
        }
     );
     for (int ii = 0; ii < 100; ++ii)
     {
        pyProc.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("this is message # {0}", ii));
     }
```

At the python script side, you just need to use built-in function [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) like below (please note the function has been renamed to raw_input in 3.x):

```
while True:
    data = raw_input()
    print(data)
```

Comment: And how to get this in Python?

Comment: raw_input is renamed to input. But it doesn't work while True:
    data = input()
with open("C:/Users/korisnik/Desktop/file.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(data)

Comment: I don't have 3.x environment handy. But the code posted above did run in 2.7

Comment: By reading your code in the comment above, I guess the problem was not at function `input`, instead it was at the mode 'w' you used in opening file.txt.  You may use mode 'w+' to avoid overwitting. A better way is to move the `with` scope out of `while` scope, in which you will not have to open the file repeatly

Comment: @user3661837, the problem in your code is the use of indentation. For having one piece of code in another's scope, you have to indenting it.

Comment: Still same, file is empty.

Comment: please try to print `data` before writing it to the file, to see what the python side actually gets.

Comment: When i run from C#, python console is empty,

Comment: I setup a 3.4 environment, and my sample code above works (of course changing raw_input to input).

Comment: @user3661837, the mode in `open` should be 'a' rather than 'w+' (I mixed things in different languages, sorry about that). http://pastebin.com/ktNiW8KD works, with writing to the disk

Comment: for the use of various mode in `open`, you may check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Can you paste links of your versions of python and pyscripter? Something else don't fork.

Comment: I download 3.5.2 from the official site https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Nothing, i will try on another machine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize the data to a common format that is accessible from both C# and Python. For example - XML or JSON. I would recommend using JSON.

Then you have several options:

- Use sockets to transfer the data.
- Use http to transfer the data.
- Write to a file from C# and read that file from Python

Sockets would probably be faster. Using http might be easier. With files, you will need to have some sort of scheduling or notification system to let your Python program know when you have written to the file.

Comment: Does anyone have a example? I am new with Python.

Comment: Do you know how to convert data to json from c#? In python, you can parse a json string using the `json` module. `import json` first and then `data = json.loads("the json string")`

Comment: [["first"],["second"]] , like this.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. This might help - http://masnun.com/2011/07/08/quick-json-parsing-with-c-sharp.html